# TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null theFunction [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I have a piece of javascript code that is like this:

```
var regex = /<img.*?src=['"](.*?)['"]/;
var image = regex.exec(input.str)[1];
```

and it gets the error when there is nothing found, when the regex is executed.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null theFunction (eval at <anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:52:23), <anonymous>:50:34) eval (eval at <anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:52:23), <anonymous>:68:20) Domain.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:53:5) Domain.run (domain.js:228:14) module.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:51:5)
```

Is there a way to stop this error from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just check if it is null.

```
var regex = /regex/;
var executedReg = regex.exec(input.str);

if (executedReg != null) {
    let image = executedReg[1];
}
```